# How can I show a floating button over all pages in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I would like to keep showing a floating button or widget in Flutter even though the page is changed by `Navigator.of(context).push()` like mini music player which placed in the bottom.

How can I implement that ??

[image]

Comment: You can create a widget you want, then create a widget like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64159024/floating-action-button-pinned-on-every-screen

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the scaffold as a layout that contains a bottom sheet, and use this layout in every page you build, passing in the title, body, etc., so that the bottom sheet is persistent in all pages. Snippet below.

[image: Persistent Bottom Sheet]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Persistent Bottom Sheet',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        brightness: Brightness.dark,
      ),
      initialRoute: "/",
      routes: {
        "/": (context) => Home(),
        "/library": (context) => Library(),
      },
    );
  }
}

class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  Home({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Layout(
      title: "Home",
      body: Center(
        child: Text("Home"),
      ),
      actions: <Widget>[
        InkWell(
          onTap: () {
            Navigator.of(context).pushNamed("/library");
          },
          child: Tooltip(
            message: "Go To Library",
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12),
              child: Icon(Icons.library_music),
            ),
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}

class Library extends StatelessWidget {
  Library({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Layout(
      title: "Library",
      body: Center(
        child: Text("Library"),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Layout extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;
  final Widget body;
  final List<Widget>? actions;

  const Layout({
    Key? key,
    required this.title,
    required this.body,
    this.actions,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Text(title),
        actions: actions,
      ),
      body: body,
      bottomSheet: Container(
        width: double.infinity,
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
        color: Theme.of(context).cardColor,
        child: Text("Persistent Bottom Sheet"),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but the bottom sheet shows refreshing animation when the page is changed because the sheet is linked to the every single page. Is there any way to make it float and be stable ?

Comment: The default page transition occurs because we are using MaterialPageRoute. If you do not want the transition animation, you can use a PageRouteBuilder. Check this answer for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57774013/16045128